# Automatically add partition conditions to WHERE clause

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, database-partitioning, trino

I have a columnar table that is partitioned by day and hour. It is stored on S3 in parquet files to be queried by Athena. Here is the CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE foo (
  -- other columns here
  dt timestamp,
  day string,
  hour string
)
PARTITIONED BY (day string, hour string)
STORED AS parquet
LOCATION 's3://foo/foo'
```

And the layout on S3 is like:

```
s3://foo/foo/day=2021-10-10/hh=00/*.parquet
s3://foo/foo/day=2021-10-10/hh=01/*.parquet
...etc
s3://foo/foo/day=2021-10-10/hh=23/*.parquet
```

So a query like the following will be fast because it only scans over one hour of parquet files because the partition columns are being used to filter it:

```
-- fast, easy to write
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE day = '2021-10-10' AND hour = '00'
```

However, the table also includes the full datetime `dt`. Usually we want to write queries for ranges that don't align to a day/hour boundary, and/or are in a different timezone.

For example, this will scan ALL parquet files and be very slow:

```
-- slow, easy to write
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE dt > '2021-10-09 23:05:00' AND dt < '2021-10-11 01:00:00'
```

It can be improved by manually calculating the `day` and `hour` that minimally enclose the time period:

```
-- fast, painful to write
SELECT * FROM foo
WHERE
  ((day, hh) IN (('2021-10-09', '23'), ('2021-10-11', '00')) OR day = '2021-10-10')
AND
  dt > '2021-10-09 23:05:00' AND dt < '2021-10-11 01:00:00'
```

Ideally this extra condition could be added transparently by the database so as to avoid having to manually add the `((day,hh) IN (...))`.

Is this possible somehow with Athena?

Comment: I can't visualize the table structure and its column. Can you add a few rows of sample data?

Comment: @TheImpaler I made an edit to hopefully clarify that!

Comment: I think you may find better answers to this question at dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've wished for this feature many times, but unfortunately Athena does not support it. You have to include both the predicate for the `dt` column and the `day` and `hour` partition keys.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote, but thanks!